# Replacing specific words in a string, given an arraylist of an index of where the words are

Tags: java

I have these two methods, one "findFour" finds the index of all the "bad words" in a given string. It puts the index of the located bad words into an arrayList and returns it. The next method "replaceFour" will find those same bad words in the same given string, and then replace those words with some symbol like "$$$$" and return the String. For example, if my input String was "Oh dang that's crap", then the findFour method would return an arrayList with [3, 13] (which is the index of the two "bad" words), then the replaceFour method would return "Oh $$$$ that's $$$$" I am trying to figure out how to basically make the replaceFour method.

```
public ArrayList<Integer> findFour(String text){
    for(int i=0; i<text.length()-4;i++){
        String fourLetter = text.substring(i, i+4);
        FourWords.add(fourLetter);
        if(fourLetter.equals(BadWords.get(0)) || fourLetter.equals(BadWords.get(1)) || fourLetter.equals(BadWords.get(2))){
            IndexofBad.add(i);
        }

    }
    return IndexofBad; //this arrayList contains index of all the bad words in the given string
}

//have to replace the bad words with a different text
public void replaceFour(String text){//Have not figured out
    newString.equals(text);
    for(int i=0; i<IndexofBad.size(); i++){

    }
}
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Oh oops. I edited the title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using basic String manipulation, like using `indexOf()` and `substring()` methods.

```
String s = "Oh crap that sucks";
List<Integer> badWordIndices = List.of(3, 13);
for (Integer i : badWordIndices) {
    int indexOfNextSpace = s.indexOf(" ", i);
    s = s.substring(0, i) + "$$$$" + (indexOfNextSpace != -1 ? s.substring(indexOfNextSpace) : "");
}
System.out.println(s);
```

**Output**

```
Oh $$$$ that $$$$
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Ive been stuck on this for a while now.

Answer (score 1):

use `String.replace` ([Oracle doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence)))

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution with List..

```
static List<String> badWords = null;
public static String replaceBadWords(String s) {
    List<String> lsStr = Arrays.asList(s.split(" "));
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(String sr: lsStr) {
        if(badWords.contains(sr)) {
            sr = "$$$";
        }
        result.add(sr);
    }
    return String.join(" ", result);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    badWords = new ArrayList<>();
    badWords.add("crap");
    badWords.add("dang");
    System.out.println(replaceBadWords("Oh dang that's crap"));
}
```